# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows with angularjs in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have set the token as header for my requests by using following code

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = 'mytoken';
```

My request header shown in my firebug is as follows.

```
X-Auth-Token    mytoken
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13
access-control-allow-orig...    *
```

In my server side code I have added following line

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("x-auth-token: mytoken");
```

Still I am receiving following error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/app/item/get. (Reason: missing token 'x-auth-token' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/app/item/get. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

If I Remove below token header everything working fine

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = 'mytoken';
```